# Redirecting the link without click

Tags: javascript, redirect

Sorry if it seems a stupid noob question, but I can't understand why this page gets me to new page without a single mouse click after loading in Chrome. I am trying to make clicking on google link to get another page... Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<h1>3 JS</h1>
<a id="googlelink" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<hr>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<hr>
</body>
</html>

<script>
document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("click", redirectToYahoo());
document.getElementById("googlelink").addEventListener("auxclick", redirectToYahooNewTab());

 function redirectToYahoo() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com";
  }

 function redirectToYahooNewTab() {
    window.open('https://www.yahoo.com', '_blank');
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. The `<script>` tag should be within `<body>`.

Comment: Yes, i see that now, it seems that I did it while copying it in notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in your addEventListener call you are *executing* the redirection function instead of passing it as parameter to addEventListener. Should be:

```
addEventListener("click", redirectToYahoo);
```

without parenthesis to avoid calling it during page load.

Comment: @DraganTomovski I added correct code for clarity. If the answer works for you, you are welcome to accept it.